# Filtering issue with Urchin 6

Tags: google-analytics, urchin

I have the following filter for one of my profile:

- filter type: Include Pattern Only
- filter field: user_defined_variable (AUTO)
- filter pattern: \[53\]
- case sensitive: no

In my content, I have the following javascript:

```
_userv=0;
urchinTracker();
__utmSetVar("various string in here");
```

Now, the issue is that in this profiles, there are files that are showing up in the report that shouldn't. For instance, for a specific profile, in the Webmaster View > Content By Title, a page with the following variable (as seen from the source) shows up :

```
__utmSetVar("[3][345]")
```

I have no idea why this is happening. The filter pattern doesn't match thus it shouldn't show up.

Comment: do you have any other filters before this one?

Comment: @CrayonViolent No, I only have one filter applied to this profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it's supposed to include files that may have a different pattern. The reason is that it will report on all the files that were seen during a single visit, which includes other files with different custom variables.

To see the report on the custom vars:

Marketing Optimization
- Visitor segment performance
-- User defined